What should I do for this Vertex AI Evaluation Problem?
I have a single label image classification project for school. I gave the data, labeled it and trained the AI for 6 hours and 18 mins. Then I came to model registry to create an evaluation. But it keeps getting the same Error. These are the screenshots. Error 3 status 400
settings
Tried to start the evaluation test but it keeps giving the same error, what can I do?
